# Why 2147483648 + 2147483648 = 0 in C?

Tags: c

Here's the code:

```
int a;
a = 2147483648 + 2147483648;
printf("%d", a);
```

I know that maximum number of int variable is 2147483647.
So, as I know, 2147483648 = -2147483648.
But why 2147483648 + 2147483648 = 0?

Comment: Well, you see, 2147483648 is 0x80000000 + 0x80000000 = 0x100000000. That doesn't fit in 32 bits, so the last 1 is lost, and it becomes 0.

Comment: Look at how it's represented in binary and how the computer adds the numbers.

Comment: If you know that `a = -a` then add `a` to both sides... `a+a = -a+a` i.e. `0`

Comment: @BradyDean C arithmetic is defined in terms of values, not representations

Answer (score 5):

2147483648 is 1 followed by 31 zeroes. If you add it twice, it simply overflows (all 32 bits will be zero and carry will be set). Since carry is basically discarded (ignored, when you store the value into a), you don't see it, all you see are 0s.

```
   10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
  +10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
  ------------------------------------  
(1)00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

Comment: "carry is basically discarded" is not true .  `2147483648` is likely to be a 64-bit value on modern system and "carry" from bit 31 goes to bit 32

Comment: Well I spoke about 32bit integers. You're right that carry goes to 32nd bit on x64, but when you attempt to store the number from register into a memory, it really is discarded IMO.

Comment: x86 also has 64-bit values .  You're right in the comment that storing the result of the addition into `a` might lose bits, but your answer doesn't reflect this. The result of the addition does not cause any overflow and still contains the `1`   (on a C99 compliant system). You could try `printf("%lld", 2147483648 + 2147483648);`

Answer (score 4):

Because your constants do not fit in an `int` they are treated as a `long` (or, if necessary, `long long`, so:

`2147483648 = 0x80000000` + another `0x80000000` = `0x100000000`, which when you assign it to `a` is truncated to 0 (assuming 4 byte `int`s.)

gcc issues a [warning](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fwHy3IOWsd2g7BrB) for the assignment.

Second one of these today.

Comment: But, if I change int to long long, and %d to %lld, it gives me same result. Why?

Comment: "is truncated to 0" - it's implementation-defined what happens here (other possibilities include raising a signal)

Comment: @Hoseong The format specifier has to match the type of `a`, which is an `int`.  The truncation happens in the assignment, not the `printf`.

Comment: @HoseongJeon this works: https://wandbox.org/permlink/3YLOUDHtMGxbQsBP

Comment: Well, that code you linked doesn't work in Visual Studio 2019. I think that you're right, but why doesn't work in VS2019?

Comment: @HoseongJeon because in MSVC `long` is a 32-bit type, but on 64-bit Linux it's a 64-bit type

Comment: @HoseongJeon ... So use long long (and %lld) instead.

Comment: @phuclv Ahh... So is long long 32-bit int MSVC too? 'cause when I change long to long long, it works same.

Comment: @PaulSanders When I change long to long long, and %ld to %lld, it works equally.

Comment: @HoseongJeon You're right.  Maybe MSVC doesn't promote the constants to a wider type.  Try 2147483648LL in the summation.

Comment: @PaulSanders Yeah. When I try with 2147483648LL, that works. But [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/data-type-ranges?view=vs-2019) says that long long is 8 byte!! What?!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213206/discussion-between-hoseong-jeon-and-paul-sanders).

Comment: MSVC applies the C90 rules for constants in the range 2^31 to 2^32-1, even while also supporting long long  (this does not conform to any standard).  Or it used to anyway, I'm not up to date with any potential recent developments in MSVC

Comment: @M.M MSVC is the first compiler to fully support C++17 so it must conform to C++11 and up where `long long` exists, unless you're chosing to use an older standard. \@HoseongJeon there are so many wrong things in your comments. The standard says that **`long long` must have at least 64 bits** and the same applies to MSVC. Promotion only applies to types smaller than int so obviously there's no promotion occur if you do `2147483648LL + 2147483648LL`

Comment: @RyanHaining it only works if `long` is wider than 32 bits (like on 64-bit Linux)

Comment: @phuclv ah of course. I should have used int64_t: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Xw0AAFISPDlr4z0X

Comment: @phuclv this is a C question

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour of this code depends on:

- which version of C you are using
- what the sizes of types are on your compiler (implementation-defined)
- perhaps other implementation-defined features

The code could output any number or raise a signal but this must be covered in the compiler's documentation.

There are two places in which the code relies on implementation-defined behaviour:  the result of the addition, and then the operation of storing the result of the addition into an `int` variable.

Also I would like to point out that C arithmetic is based on *values*, not representations. The answer does NOT depend on 2's complement or binary carries or anything like that. `2147483648` is always a large positive integer , it is not a negative number. Adding two positive numbers cannot produce a negative number either. This is commonly misunderstood.

---

Here are some example cases:

- In a C90 implementation where  `long` is 32 bits, `2147483648` has type either `unsigned int` or `unsigned long`. According to the definition of unsigned arithmetic the result is the mathematical value of 2147483648 + 2147483648 modulo 2^32 which works out to `0`.
- On an implementation where `int` is 32-bit and `long` is 64-bit, `2147483648` has type `long`. Then the result of the addition has type `long` and value `4294967296` .  Then, assigning this value to an `int` is an out-of-range assignment causing implementation-defined behaviour. One common way that implementations define this is truncating higher bits.  Raising a signal is another option.
- On a normal C99 implementation with 32-bit `long` and 64-bit `long long` then the case is quite similar to the previous bullet except the type is `long long`.
- There could be some esoteric system with a 33-bit `long` where the addition then causes undefined behaviour due to overflow , but we generally don't worry about that and assume nobody would ever design such a system . (There are systems with 36-bit integers though!)
- Non-conforming compilers such as MSVC could of course do something different .

Comment: Okay. I think you're talking some great ideas. Can you answer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61625574/msvc-2019-long-long-variable), which I just asked about MSVC long long?

Comment: Re “assume nobody would ever design such a system”: I could see somebody implementing C with tweakable settings for purposes of exploring the standard, testing code for incorrect assumptions about portability, and so on, rather for the use of directly producing production executables.

Comment: @phuclv https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/uPdHYs  , oops .  This cannot give `4` in ISO C99 or later, nor in ISO C++11 or later.   (Assuming 8-bit char).  Also, this is a C question and you link to a C++ conformance page.