# MSVC 2019 long long variable

Tags: c++, c

I'm using MSVC 2019.

So, I just searched [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/data-type-ranges?view=vs-2019).
They says that `long long` is 8 byte, and range of values is -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

So, what I thought is, that this would work:

```
long long a = 2147483648 + 2147483648;
printf("%lld", a);
```

I thought it would print `4294967296`, which equals to `2147483648 + 2147483648`.

But it prints `0` to me.....

So, this time I tried little differently:

```
long long a = 2147483648;
printf("%lld", a + a);
```

and it prints `4294967296`!!!

So here are two questions.

FIRST: What is difference between those codes?

SECOND: Why the first code gives me wrong number(0)?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: your literals are still `int` sized.

Comment: @Amadeus, it might aswell, it's his/her question.

Comment: @DanielA.White I know that I should use something like `2147483628LL`. But, then why does the second code works in spite of using just `2147483628` ?

Comment: You should not dual tag your question as the C compiler is a different thing to the C++ compiler and they may use different rules.  Instead tag according to which compiler you are actually using

Comment: @HoseongJeon because the type of `a` is `long long`, it isn't a literal at that point.

Comment: This is something we don't see every day, a question closed as a duplicate of a question posted by the same person.

Answer (score 3):

The result of `2147483648 + 2147483648` depends on the type of `2147483648`  , it does not take into account that you later store the result into a `long long` variable.

MSVC's C compiler does not conform to the C99 or later standards, and it makes `2147483648` have the type `unsigned long` which is a 32-bit type. (This was correct behaviour in C90).  Then the result of the addition is `(unsigned long)0` as per the definition of unsigned arithmetic.

Comment: Okay, got it. Then if I plus three times, like this: `long long a = 2147483648 + 2147483648 + 2147483648;`, it gives me `2147483648`!! `2147483648 + 2147483648 = 0`, and isn't `0 + 2147483648 = -2147483648` because `0` and `2147483648` are `int`?

Comment: Ahh... I'm getting dizzy.... LOL

Answer (score 2):

> FIRST: What is difference between those codes?

```
long long a = 2147483648 + 2147483648;
```

This actually works as-intended with GCC (it prints `4294967296`), but VC++ prints `0`.

```
long long a = 2147483648;
```

The results are different because in the first case the integer literals are added as though they're `int`, not `long long` so the intermediate result overflows.

In the second case the addition is correct because there's no overflow because the `+` operator is being used with `long long` operands.

> SECOND: Why the first code gives me wrong number(0)?

Integer literals are typed as `int` by default unless you specify a type suffix. The C++ compiler will not automatically widen integers (even though in this case the context and developer's intent is clear).

So this code...

```
long long a = 2147483648 + 2147483648;
```

...is equivalent to this:

```
int x = 2147483648;
int y = 2147483648;
int z = x + y;
long long a = z;
```

You can fix this by using the `long` integer literal suffix: `LL`:

```
long long a = 2147483648LL + 2147483648LL;
```

Comment: Your equivalence would not hold on any system with 32-bit `int` (since the constant is too large for `int` and therefore has some other type)

Answer (score 2):

The constant `2147483648` is an `unsigned int` (or `unsigned long`) literal and, as such, is a 4-byte value on the platform you are using. Thus, when you add two such constants together (as in your first code snippet), the operation is performed in 4 bytes, and overflows (giving zero). Only *after* the addition is performed is the result promoted to a `long long` (but, by then. the damage is done).

In your second code snippet, you are adding two variables that are explicitly declared as `long long` and, thus, the addition is performed as an 8-byte operation.

To 'fix' the first snippet, and force the constants to be 8-byte values, you need to add the `LL` (or `ll`) suffix:

```c
long long a = 2147483648LL + 2147483648LL;
```